# ignore characters when using sql distinct or groupby

Tags: sql

I am using sql distinct to select unique data from csv, how do I make strings like below become one.

- column1, column2
- Young, boy & the dresser, 1
- Young boy & the dresser , 2
- GPs: who is there, 1
- GPs who is there, 2

I am using the code here

```sql
select distinct(colum1) as c1 from Table
sum(column2) as c2
group by c1
```

Here is my expected result

- c1, c2
- Young, boy & the dresser, 3
- GPs: who is there, 3

OR

- Young boy & the dresser, 3
- GPs who is there, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If comma, colon and trailing spaces are the only issues you have, you could try something like this:

```
select col1, sum(col2)
from 
(select rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(col1,',',''),':',''))) as col1, col2) t
group by col1;
```

Comment: Thanks @String Theory